# Button js does not work on any class, but Id yes

Tags: javascript

I want some behaviour on all my div classes, but somehow nothing happens nowhere. When I use `getElementById` then it works only the first, this I know because the div Id is unique. But why now it does not work on all my classes?

Also, I try to make that the button text changes with opening and closing it. I used `button onclick="myFunction(this)"` and also I set the `button value="button text"` and then in my javascript I used `innerHTML` but also no luck. If you want I can show what I tried exactly, well, I tried multiple ways of doing it, but no luck.

```
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("textbox");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

and

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
    <div class="textbox"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
    <div class="textbox"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
    <div class="textbox"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
    <div class="textbox"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
    <div class="textbox"></div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
    <div class="textbox"></div>
```

Comment: A group of elements doesn't have a style.  Individual elements do, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getElementsByClassName("textbox")` alway return array, you can not treat array as DOM, you need use index for your case, but you dont know the index so need you `nextElementSibling` to find suitable div.

Solution: You can pass `this` to click event and use `nextElementSibling` to get your div

```
function myFunction(item) {

            var x = item.nextElementSibling;
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
}
```

```js
function myFunction(item) {
//console.log(item.nextElementSibling);
            var x = item.nextElementSibling;
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
           }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="button text">A</button>
                <div class="textbox">A</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="button text">B</button>
                <div class="textbox">B</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="button text">C</button>
                <div class="textbox">C</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="button text">D</button>
                <div class="textbox">D</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="button text">E</button>
                <div class="textbox">E</div>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="button text">F</button>
                <div class="textbox">F</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which is an array-like object, but is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try  with querySelectorAll , like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.querySelectorAll(".textbox");
 x.forEach(ele=>{
  if (ele.style.display === "none") {
   ele.style.display = "block";
  } else {
   ele.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
 )
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
                <div class="textbox"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
                <div class="textbox"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
                <div class="textbox"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
                <div class="textbox"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
                <div class="textbox"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()" value="button text"></button>
                <div class="textbox"></div>
```